How to correctly set the filename in Laravel for a s3 download?
I am working with an s3 bucket in laravel (11) and have following function in my controller to dowload a given file to chrome:
public function downloadFile(Materials $material) 
   {

        Gate::authorize('view', $material);
        $fileInfo = pathinfo($material->filename);
        $filename = urlencode($material->name) . "." . $fileInfo['extension'];
        return Storage::disk('s3')->response( $material->filename, $filename );
    }

The problem is, that the file does not have the filename in $filename after the download. It is the hash from s3.
But the header seems ok?
Content-Disposition:
inline; filename="DatenschutzerklC3A4rung+Muster.docx"; filename*=utf-8''Datenschutzerkl%25C3%25A4rung%2BMuster.docx

What I also tried so far is:
# number 1
return Storage::disk('s3')->response(
        $material->filename,
        urldecode($filename),
        ['Content-Disposition' => 'attachment']
    );
# number 2
return Storage::disk('s3')->response(
    $material->filename,
    $filename,
    ['Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename=\"$filename\"; filename*=UTF-8''$filename"]
);

But no Luck ... did I get something wrong?

If you just want to stream the file as a download to the browser, you could try the following:
return response()->streamDownload(function () {
    echo Storage::disk('s3')->get($filename);
}, $material->filename);

